# 400 Bad Request error with asp .net core hosted with Dokku on DigitalOcean

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx-config, dokku

I have problem with my asp .net core web api. I set up authorization with jwt.
Everything works perfectly on localhost. When I upload to Dokku I am unable to send POST to server, I am getting 400.

Here is my nginx config which is generated from sigil file:

```
{{ range $port_map := .PROXY_PORT_MAP | split " " }}
{{ $port_map_list := $port_map | split ":" }}
{{ $scheme := index $port_map_list 0 }}
{{ $listen_port := index $port_map_list 1 }}
{{ $upstream_port := index $port_map_list 2 }}

{{ if eq $scheme "http" }}
server {
  listen      [::]:{{ $listen_port }};
  listen      {{ $listen_port }};
  {{ if $.NOSSL_SERVER_NAME }}server_name {{ $.NOSSL_SERVER_NAME }}; {{ end }}
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/{{ $.APP }}-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/{{ $.APP }}-error.log;
{{ if (and (eq $listen_port "80") ($.SSL_INUSE)) }}
  return 301 https://$host:{{ $.PROXY_SSL_PORT }}$request_uri;
{{ else }}
  location    / {

    ###CORS-START###
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
       #
       # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
       #
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
       #
       # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
       #
       add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
       add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
       add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
       return 204;
    }
    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
    ###CORS-END###

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://{{ $.APP }}-{{ $upstream_port }};
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;

    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
  }
  include {{ $.DOKKU_ROOT }}/{{ $.APP }}/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;

  error_page 400 401 402 403 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 /400-error.html;
  location /400-error.html {
    root {{ $.DOKKU_LIB_ROOT }}/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 404 /404-error.html;
  location /404-error.html {
    root {{ $.DOKKU_LIB_ROOT }}/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 /500-error.html;
  location /500-error.html {
    root {{ $.DOKKU_LIB_ROOT }}/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }
{{ end }}
}
{{ else if eq $scheme "https"}}
server {
  listen      [::]:{{ $listen_port }} ssl {{ if eq $.HTTP2_SUPPORTED "true" }}http2{{ else if eq $.SPDY_SUPPORTED "true" }}spdy{{ end }};
  listen      {{ $listen_port }} ssl {{ if eq $.HTTP2_SUPPORTED "true" }}http2{{ else if eq $.SPDY_SUPPORTED "true" }}spdy{{ end }};
  {{ if $.SSL_SERVER_NAME }}server_name {{ $.SSL_SERVER_NAME }}; {{ end }}
  {{ if $.NOSSL_SERVER_NAME }}server_name {{ $.NOSSL_SERVER_NAME }}; {{ end }}
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/{{ $.APP }}-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/{{ $.APP }}-error.log;

  ssl_certificate     {{ $.APP_SSL_PATH }}/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key {{ $.APP_SSL_PATH }}/server.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  keepalive_timeout   70;
  {{ if and (eq $.SPDY_SUPPORTED "true") (ne $.HTTP2_SUPPORTED "true") }}add_header          Alternate-Protocol  {{ $.PROXY_SSL_PORT }}:npn-spdy/2;{{ end }}

  location    / {

    ###CORS-START###
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
       #
       # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
       #
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
       #
       # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
       #
       add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
       add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
       add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
       return 204;
    }
    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,,Authorization';
       add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
    ###CORS-END###
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://{{ $.APP }}-{{ $upstream_port }};
    {{ if eq $.HTTP2_PUSH_SUPPORTED "true" }}http2_push_preload on; {{ end }}
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
  }
  include {{ $.DOKKU_ROOT }}/{{ $.APP }}/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;

  error_page 400 401 402 403 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 /400-error.html;
  location /400-error.html {
    root {{ $.DOKKU_LIB_ROOT }}/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 404 /404-error.html;
  location /404-error.html {
    root {{ $.DOKKU_LIB_ROOT }}/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 /500-error.html;
  location /500-error.html {
    root {{ $.DOKKU_LIB_ROOT }}/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }
}
{{ end }}{{ end }}

{{ if $.DOKKU_APP_LISTENERS }}
{{ range $upstream_port := $.PROXY_UPSTREAM_PORTS | split " " }}
upstream {{ $.APP }}-{{ $upstream_port }} {
{{ range $listeners := $.DOKKU_APP_LISTENERS | split " " }}
{{ $listener_list := $listeners | split ":" }}
{{ $listener_ip := index $listener_list 0 }}
  server {{ $listener_ip }}:{{ $upstream_port }};{{ end }}
}
{{ end }}{{ end }}
```

In asp app cors is enabled and everything is allowed.

@EDIT

There is the problem. When I run localy my app(asp .net core) on IIS Express then everything is ok with post method. Once it is upload to digital ocean to dokku I am getting 400. I am sending the same data with with postaman to my local IIS Express and to Dokku. I think it is related with nginx or dokku. I am using docker container. I think it's CORS problem.

Comment: You have a 400 Bad Request problem. The only reason your browser reports a CORS-related message about it is that your server doesn’t include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the 400 error response. Servers by default typically will only end up adding your custom application-set headers to 2xx. But even if the 400 error includes the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header you’d still have a 400 problem to fix. So in this case the CORS-config snippet from your server code isn’t very relevant. What would instead by more relevant is a snippet of your frontend JavaScript code.

Comment: There is the problem. When I run localy my app(asp .net core) on IIS Express then everything is ok with post method.  Once it is upload to digital ocean to dokku I am getting 400. I am sending the same data with with postaman to my local IIS Express and to Dokku. I think it is related with nginx or dokku. I am using docker container. I think it's CORS problem.

Comment: What are the exact error messages the browser is logging in the devtools console? What messages is the receiving server logging in the server logs on the server side before it responds with the 400?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple. When using Docker you use also nginx. I exposed only one port from my asp .net core app. It was http one. Nginx was trying to upgrade to https and it was unable to do because there wasn't an ssl port for docker. Remove upgrade from nginx config when only exposing http port

Comment: Can you explain how did you do this?
"Remove upgrade from nginx config when only exposing http port"

Comment: Dokku let you add custom nginx config per app. Add nginx file to app folder in docker image and dokku will use your template. There is link to dokku docs: http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/configuration/nginx/#customizing-the-nginx-configuration